# Python3: Finding multiple JSON objects within a byte array

Tags: json, python-3.x, pyserial

I have byte arrays of various sizes coming over serial port that must be converted into JSON objects.

**Problem**

The problem is that multiple messages can come across at the exact same time. When I decode the arrays, the data looks like this:

```
{"time":1571813129,"device":"abc","count":0}{"time":1571813129,"device":"def","count":0}
```

Where multiple strings are together that I'm trying to separate in a simple way to then convert into JSON.

**Code**

```
x = ser1.read(256)
if x:
    x = x.decode()
```

I have also tried `ser1.readline()` but the data is still on the same line so I'm back to the same problem.

**Question**

What would be the best way to handle this situation?

- The strings are of varying length (I put `read(256)` to be more than enough)
- There are multiple messages coming in at the same time (currently strings but I want to split into the individual JSON objects)

Answer (score 0):

You could collect fragments into a string, and act on finding a `}{` in it

```
buf=''
while True:
  frag=ser1.read(256)
  buf.append(frag.decode()) # perhaps with that if, I do not know the API
  try
    i=buf.find('}{')
    while i>=0:
      msg=json.loads(buf[:i+1])
      use(msg)
      buf=buf[i+1:]
      i=buf.find('}{')
```

Comment: What is `use()`?

Comment: @Emile `use()` is where you use the decoded message.

Answer (score 0):

After posting the question, I went ahead to find the `}` in the string. Then loop over the positions - using them as the start and end for slicing it up. Not pretty but it works.

```
def find_char(data, c):
    return [pos for pos, char in enumerate(data) if char == c]


def find_objects(data):
    json_objects = []
    # Find the '}'
    pos_list = find_char(data, '}')
    # Loop over positions of }
    for x in pos_list:
        p = pos_list.index(x)
        # If the first object
        if p == 0:
            start = 0
            end = x + 1
        else:
            # For multiple objects
            if len(data) == x:
                # If the last object
                end = x
            else:
                # If in the middle of the string
                end = x + 1
            start = pos_list[p - 1] + 1
        json_objects.append(data[start:end])
    return json_objects
```